# Time series in R: How to set week period across two years?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have time series with week period (7 days) across two years. I have 58 values. Start is: `2017-08-05`, end: `2018-09-08`. I need work with this time series in R - make predictions with SARIMA model etc. But I have problem with define period/frequency in R. When I use decompose function I get error: `"time series has no or less than 2 periods"`. Arima function does not work properly. Detailed information are bellow. What way I can import my data for use in R with requested frequency please?

My data (short example):

File: sessions2.csv

```
date        count
11.11.2017  55053
18.11.2017  45256
25.11.2017  59091
2.12.2017   50030
9.12.2017   41769
16.12.2017  63042
23.12.2017  51838
30.12.2017  47652
6.1.2018    18731
13.1.2018   54470
20.1.2018   22514
27.1.2018   63818
3.2.2018    51605
10.2.2018   26312
17.2.2018   11111
```

data1.csv contains only values. For example:

```
53053
45256
59091
50045
41769
65042
51838
```

I tried in R:

```
sessions1 <- scan("data1.csv")
sessionsTS <- ts(sessions1, frequency=52, start=decimal_date(ymd("2017-11-11")))
```

Output sessionsTS and errors:

```
> sessionsTS
Time Series:
Start = 2017.59178082192 
End = 2018.68418328598 
Frequency = 52
```

*What time format represent these numbers (Start, End) please? And what way I can use for convert to decimal date?*

```
> sessionsComponents <- decompose(sessionsTS)
Error in decompose(sessionsTS) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods

> arima(sessionsTS, order = c(0, 1, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), period = 52), xreg = NULL, include.mean = TRUE)
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

> fit <- Arima(sessionsTS, order = c(0, 1, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), period = 52))
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

> sarima(sessionsTS,1,1,0,2,0,0,52)
Error in sarima(sessionsTS, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 52) : 
  unused arguments (0, 0, 52)
```

Next I tried:

```
dataSeries <- read.table("sessions2.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", row.names=1)
dataTS <- as.xts(dataSeries , frequency=52, start=decimal_date(ymd("2017-11-11")))

> sessionsComponents2 <- decompose(dataTS)
Error in decompose(dataTS) : time series has no or less than 2 periods 

> model = Arima(dataTS, order=c(0,1,0), seasonal = c(2,0,0))
> model
Series: dataTS 
ARIMA(0,1,0)
```

In this case Arima is used without seasonality...

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is sampled weekly, so if the period also is one week you need to set `frequency=1`, but at that point there is no point in doing seasonal modeling. It makes sense to have a yearly period, as you have done by setting `frequency=52`, but then you don't have enough periods for doing any estimations, you'd need at least 104 observations (at least two periods, as the error message explains) for that.

So in short, you can't do what you want to do do unless you get more data.

A partial answer for your questions about `ts()` and the time format. If you do it like this:

```
tt <- read.table(text="
date        count
11.11.2017  55053
18.11.2017  45256
25.11.2017  59091
2.12.2017   50030
9.12.2017   41769
16.12.2017  63042
23.12.2017  51838
30.12.2017  47652
6.1.2018    18731
13.1.2018   54470
20.1.2018   22514
27.1.2018   63818
3.2.2018    51605
10.2.2018   26312
17.2.2018   11111", header=TRUE)

tt$date <- as.Date(tt$date, format="%d.%m.%Y")

ts(tt$count, frequency=52, start=c(2017, 45))
# Time Series:
# Start = c(2017, 45) 
# End = c(2018, 7) 
# Frequency = 52 
#  [1] 55053 45256 59091 50030 41769 63042 51838 47652 18731
#      54470 22514 63818 51605 26312 11111
```

The `start` is at the 45'th week of 2017, and the `end` is at the 7'th week of 2018.

You can find the weeknumbers using `format(tt$date, "%W")`. Look at `?strptime` for more details and to see what `%W` means.

Comment: many thanks for answer. Really do not exist any way for estimations only with 58 observations? :-( Other software for example NCSS allows SARIMA estimation only with 58 observations with week period...

Comment: You can fit a basic ARIMA model to your data, just not a seasonal one with yearly period. I'm sure you can intuit that a seasonal fit will be better the more periods you can study/learn from. With less than two periods you simply do not have enough data to learn from and predict what the underlying process is. A bit like linear regression on less than two points, quite meaningless.

Comment: Put very simply: in a basic ARIMA model you consider how an observation relates to the previous observation, and the one before, and the one before… depending on the p, d, q orders. The seasonal component of a SARIMA model considers how an observation relates to an observation one _period_ before, and one period before that, and so on. So if your period is 52 long, but only have 58 observations, the vast majority of observations don't have another observation to compare to. You'd need at least 104 observations, but even that will give you a very poor model estimate.

Comment: hmm, it is interesting. But when I use Gretl or NCSS and I set week period results with SARIMA are much more accurate like when I use only ARIMA. These programs allow use of SARIMA with only 58 observations, why?

Comment: I don't know how Gretl and NCSS works, but I would not trust any confidence intervals of seasonal components estimated on less than two periods. This might be a good question for [stats.se], where they deal with this sort of nitty gritty statistical theory stuff much better. After a bit of searching I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200374/detecting-seasonality-with-only-one-full-period-of-data?rq=1) related question, but you could ask a new one focused on SARIMA forecast.